# Are Parentheses Still Optional in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I run, per [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-collect)

```
a = [:code]
a.collect { |x| x.to_s } # => ["code"]
```

However if I run

```
a = [:code]
a.collect({ |x| x.to_s }) # => SyntaxError
```

As far as I know, ruby has optional parens.  How is my syntax getting screwed up here?  This is an even bigger problem for me because I want to chain another function after this one, so I require the parens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't passing the block as a parameter to the parenthesis.

```
a.collect { |x| x.to_s }
```

is the same as

```
a.collect() {|x| x.to_s }
```

is the same as

```
a.collect() do |x|
  x.to_s
end
```

And all of that is fairly close to this as well:

```
block = -> (x) {x.to_s}   # Shortcut 'stabby' syntax for lambda{|x| x.to_s}
a.collect(&block) # Or a.collect &block
```

Comment: You're getting the check once I can.  That makes so much sense.

Comment: I also added an example of sending a block as a parameter, but it works a little differently, using `&blockVariable` syntax in the method arguments.

Comment: Oh also, if you want to chain another method afterwards you can just add a `.` after the end of the block and it will work just fine.  `a.collect { |x| x.to_s }.size`, for instance.  If you're using rails you can use `a.collect(&:to_s)` instead of the block too :)